# Babel - how to pull out the statement

Tags: babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to simplify intentionally obfuscated Javascript. One example of code can look like following

```
if (js = jq, d[js(646)](d[js(857)], js(606))) {}
```

I would like to pull out statements in the if condition and just keep last test but could not figure out how to do it using babel.

This is a standalone javascript program executed using node and I am able to get AST of script under consideration.

How do I achieve this using babel.